# Replace Text (preg_replace)

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

I have a variable $text, with the value:

```
...
[one_fourth]
[quote autor="Someone"]
"This is a quote"
[/quote]
[/one_fourth]
...
```

I want to replace/delete everything between "[quote" and "[/quote]" including "[quote" and "[/quote]". This is what I tried:

```
$text = preg_replace("/\[quote.*\[\/quote\]/", '', $text);
```

But I had no success. How do I manage this?

Thank you,

dee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works

```
$text = preg_replace("/\[quote.*\[\/quote\]/s", '', $text);
```

you have to tell php that the `.` has to match line breaks (parameter `s` after the closing `/`)

Comment: Exactly! Thank you, worked like a charm!
The little things... thank you for your explanation.

Comment: You don't need the parentheses, just the `s` modifier.

Answer (score -1):

```
use 
<?php
echo str_replace("\"","",$text);
?>
```

Comment: How is that piece of code replacing/deleting everything between "[quote" and "[/quote]" including "[quote" and "[/quote]"? DId you try it yourself? You are just removing ".

Comment: yes, in my code i have used this function many times and it helps me for replacing this quotes. str_replace() is an alternate of preg_replace(). only difference is that str_replace() deals faster than preg_replace()

Comment: He doesn't want to replace double-quote characters, he wants to replace sections of the text surrounded by the strings `[quote]` and `[/quote]`.

Comment: @Deval You really need to read up on regular expressions. They are a whole different beast than only substring-matching/replacing. str_replace is in no way a replacement for regexp.

Answer (score -1):

here you go

```
  $text = preg_replace("#\[quote(.*)\]\s*(.*)\s*\[\/quote\]#","$1 $2", $text);
```